# difficult asymptotic(recurrence) function (algorithm analysis)

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

i am stuck on this one and i don't know how to solve it, no matter what i try i just can't find a way to play with the function so i can represent it in a way that will allow me to find a g(n), so that g(n) is T(n)∈Θ(g(n))

the function i am having trouble with is:

$`T(n)=4n^4T(\sqrt n) +(n^6lgn+3lg^7n)(2n^2lgn+lg^3n)`$

additionally, if you can - could you please check if i am on the right path with:

$`T(n)=T(n-1)+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}`$

to solve it i tried to use: $`T(n)-T(n-1)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}`$ iff $`(T(n)-T(n-1))+(T(n-1)-T(n-2))+\ldots+(T(2)-T(1))=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)^2}+....`$ iff $`(T(n)-T(n-1))+(T(n-1)-T(n-2))+\ldots+(T(2)-T(1))=T(n)=T(1)+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{n^2}`$ and then using the harmonic series formula. however i don't know how to continue and finish it and find the asymptotic boundaries to solve it

i hope that on the second i am on the right path. however i don't know how to solve the first one at all. if i've done any mistakes, please show me the right way so i can improve my mistakes.

thank you very much for your help

sorry that for some reason math doesn't show correctly here

Comment: Stackoverflow does not support embedded LaTeX; please either write them in "plain code" style or use an external renderer such as CodeCogs. Are there two questions here, i.e. two functions you need help with?

Comment: there's one question i don't know even how to approach because it's difficult, and another oe i'm half way through, i think.

Comment: i on't know how to write math in "plain code"

Comment: As in e.g. `T(n) = T(n-1) + 1/n + 1/n^2` is much clearer than directly pasting LaTeX.

Comment: The first problem is a little more tedious, but basically you only need to consider the largest term in the expanded parentheses. For the second problem, see these pages on the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler's_approach).

Comment: couldn't solve them both. would relly appreciate seeing your attempt to understand what i've done wrong

Comment: I will post tomorrow; but the links I added pretty much give the solution for question two already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments:

---

Solving **(2)** first since it is more straightforward.

Your expansion attempt is correct. Writing it slightly differently:

[image]

- **A**, harmonic series - asymptotically equal to the natural logarithm:

  [image]

  `γ = 0.57721...` is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).
- **B**, sum of inverse squares - the infinite sum is the famous [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem):

  [image]

  Which is `1.6449...`. Therefore since **B** is monotonically increasing, it will always be `O(1)`.

> The total complexity of **(2)** is simply `Θ(log n)`.

---

**(1)** is a little more tedious.

- *Little-o* notation: *strictly* lower complexity class, i.e.:

  [image]
- Assume a set of `N` functions `{F_i}` is ordered in decreasing order of complexity, i.e. `F2 = o(F1)` etc. Take a linear combination of them:

  [image]

  Thus a sum of different functions is asymptotically equal to the one with the highest growth rate.
- To sort the terms in the expansion of the two parentheses, note that

  [image]

  Provable by applying [L'Hopital's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial). So the only asymptotically significant term is `n^6 log n * 2n^2 log n = 2n^8 log^2 n`.
- Expand the summation as before, note that i) the factor `4n^4` accumulates, ii) the parameter for the `m`-th expansion is `n^(1/(2^m))` (repeated square-root).

  The new term added by the `m`-th expansion is therefore (will assume you know how to do this since you were able to do the same for **(2)**):

  [image]

  Rather surprisingly, each added term is precisely equal to the first.
- Assume that the stopping condition for recursive expansion is `n < 2` (which of course rounds down to `T(1)`):

  [image]

  Since each added term `t_m` is always the same, simply multiply by the maximum number of expansions:

> Function **(1)** is
>
> [image]

Comment: thank you very much, i'll study your answer in the morning. thak you o much for helping me